# Spark UDF function gets called each time member of the struct is accessed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have UDF function that is returning case class `ProcessedResult`. Inside this UDF I'm using Singleton class that doing some processing.

Example

```
case class ProcessedResult(
                     field1:String = null,
                     field2:String = null,
                     field3:String = null,
                     field4:String = null,
                     field5:String = null
                    )

val sampleudf = udf((data: String) => {
  println("Processing")
  // processing
  ProcessedResult(field1, field2, field3, field4, field5)
})

val df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("test1"),("test2"),("test3"),("test4"),("test5"),("test6")
)).toDF("data")

val df2 = df1.withColumn("processed", sampleudf($"data"))
df2.printSchema()
```

Struct of this data:

```
 |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |-- processed: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field3: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field5: string (nullable = true)
```

Ok, lets query our data

```
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("datas")

spark.sql(
  s"""
     |SELECT
     |processed.field1,
     |processed.field2,
     |processed.field3,
     |processed.field4,
     |processed.field5
     |FROM datas
    """.stripMargin).collect().foreach(println)
```

I'm getting string "Processing" 30 times in return! It means our UDF was called 30 times! We had only 6 rows with 5 columns returned by our UDF. But, UDF is getting called each time I'm accessing any of the struct's column! What is the point of that ? 30 calls to the UDF for 5 rows ? Why struct isn't cached or remembered in any way ? Having complex UDF functions makes it impossible to use UDF effectively.